# In node.js, Why is middleware called so many times when directing to a page with Expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Hi I have a question about how middleware is called in Express.js app?
Basically I have code as following:

```js
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', port);


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/frontend', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'frontend')));
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log('every request?!?!');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api',api);
app.use('/socket', socket);
```

Notice I have console.log ('every request?') to check how many time that header setting function is called. Than I got this in my console:

```
every request?!?!
GET /app 304 2.261 ms - -
GET /frontend/css/myAppStyle.css 304 0.674 ms - -
GET /frontend/app/myApp.js 304 1.203 ms - -
GET /frontend/app/services/service.js 304 1.569 ms - -
GET /frontend/app/controllers/ctrls.js 304 2.155 ms - -
GET /frontend/app/directives/directives.js 304 1.560 ms - -
GET /frontend/img/profile.JPG 304 1.438 ms - -
every request?!?!
every request?!?!
GET /api/newcustomers 304 3.044 ms - -
GET /api/newpurchase 304 2.581 ms - -
GET /frontend/app/views/home.html 304 1.854 ms - -
every request?!?!
every request?!?!
GET /api/customerdata 304 1.206 ms - -
GET /api/newcustomers 304 1.055 ms - -
every request?!?!
GET /api/newpurchase 304 0.886 ms - -
```

its simply just a login function, basically check whether user exists, then direct to  /app,

My question: why is the header setting function called so many time? how to have control over how many times a middleware should be used? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you set a route for `/login` with `app.get('/login',...` rather than using middleware? Middleware is meant to be called with each request.

Comment: You can set up an express Router so that the middleware is only called whenever that router is executed.  See here on using express routers: 

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: I did, im just trying to understand if middleware is on application level, how is it called. But there are actually 13 request there while only 6 "every request"? it doesn't look like its called on every request?

Comment: I see! So static files are not considered request?!?

Comment: @Shaun: Static files are requests, only you have installed the static middleware before yours and it eats up the entire connection and stops processing all later middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

Expressjs middlewares are called on every request if the URL provided inside the midleware is matching the url requested.

If no url passed as first argument on middleware it will be called on each request.

```
app.use('/some-route', someMiddlewareFunc)
```

If you will write the middleware in the following way it will be called only for routes matching "/some-route"

Middlewares are very usefull if you need to process the request for all of your routes, or for specific patterns. i.e authentication, logging, parsing and etc.

Comment: Thanks, but there are actually 13 request there while only 6 "every request"?  it doesn't look like its called on every request?

Comment: Yep :) in production i would suggest using proxy like nginx for serving static files

Comment: @Shaun - Express handlers are executed in the order you specify them in your code so your static requests are handled BEFORE the middleware so the middleware is not going to be called for them because `express.static()` is before the `app.use()` middleware.